# Can I use direct.label() with ggplot's scale_colour_manual()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code assigns a manual color scale of red and black to my points:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(directlabels)
dtest <- data.frame(x=1:20,
                  y=rnorm(20,0,5),
                  v=seq(1,2))
p <- ggplot(dtest, aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(v))) + geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","black"))
p #this looks good; red and black as intended

direct.label(p) #this falls back on the default colors
```

But when I apply `direct.label()` to the same plot, it overrides the color scale in favor of the `ggplot` default. Is there a way to prevent this? If not, what's the best way to assign new colors to the default ggplot scale?
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hadley, 
I added the require() statements to load ggplot2 and directlabels, and added a direct.label(p) command at the end. What else did you have in mind?

Comment: MW, what are you trying to accomplish with directlabels?  You can override the default coloring with scale_colour_manual as you have done.

What am I missing?

Comment: Drew,
When you run the final direct.label() command in the code above, does it apply the red/black scale to the points and labels? Because it's not doing so for me. It's plotting the points and labels in salmon and teal, which is what ggplot uses when I don't specify my manual scale..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because direct.label(p) operates by adding the label geom to p, then by hiding the color legend, since labeling the colors twice would be redundant. One way to hide the color legend is by adding scale_colour_discrete(legend=FALSE), and this is what I do inside of direct.label. So when directlabels applies scale_colour_discrete, your scale_colour_manual will be lost. The workaround is to use the following idiom:

```
p <- ggplot(...)
direct.label(p)+
  scale_colour_manual(...)
```